# javascript, some function explanation?

Tags: javascript

What does the following peace of code mean?

```
someName.UI = function(){
   var someName;
       if (!someName) 
              someName= {};

      someName.UI = function() {      
        var player = 1;
      }
  //some code here
}
```

i'm quite new to javascript and this is the first i've seen something like this.

Comment: Java or javascript? If javascript someName is namespace for function UI.

Comment: It's obviously not java

Comment: did i misspell it ? sorry about that, got confused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var someName;
```

This is the variable name declaration.

```
if (!someName) 
    someName= {};
```

When the variable is `null` or otherwise empty, create a new empty object in it.

```
someName.UI = function() {      
    var player = 1;
}
```

Create the member `UI` in the object holding a function which will create a variable with a value of `1`.

```
someName.UI();
```

This would be the call to this function.

Comment: This is the explanation for JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: Nice explanation with clarity. +1 !

Comment: `someName` is local, `!someName` will always be true.

Comment: note: this codesnippet makes no sense. If you want to reference the global object `if(!somename)` could never be true, else it would through a Reference error right in the beginning . However somename is defined in the local scope but not initialized, thus this condition is always true.

Comment: @djechlin the problem isn't that it's local, the problem is that it's not been initialized with anything. But yes, the test is unneeded.

Comment: If it weren't local to the function then on subsequent runs it would be initialized to something. But the reference is redeclared each time.

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to create objects in javascript.

One of them is to create a function.

```
1. var obj = function(id){ this.id = id; } <-- class with constructor for creating object
   var objInstance = new obj(); <-- typeof objInstance === "object", typeof obj === "function"
2. var obj2 = {}
3. var obj3 = new Object()
```

Comment: this first one is a simple function expression. So in the a sense obj is a function and not an object. You'd rather call it a constructor function but not necessarily an object.

Comment: Javascript is object based language. Each function is an object. `"Everything" in JavaScript is an Object` http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_intro.asp, `functions as object constructors` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript

Comment: The first one is full operated object, with properties and methods.

Comment: Well, you should read [this](http://www.w3fools.com/) and then you know why you can't rely on w3schools. Javascript has primitive values which are not objects. `var t1 = "foo";typeof t2 === "string";var t2 = new String("bar");typeof t2 === "object";` While `if("")` yields false, `if(new String(""))` yields true. Complex data types have object somewhere in their prototype chain, yes that's true. nonetheless `var obj = function(id){ this.id = id; };typeof obj === "function"`. It's too much to explain in the comment section, but you should read into this a little bit further.

Comment: I see it online. Try again in a minute.

Comment: You're right. typeof obj === "function" but if you instantiate obj to variable: var s = new obj(), typeof s === "object". Then 'obj' acts like class in oop languages.